# Limit questions - Struggling

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling between these 2 limit questions, can someone please help?

1. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)\sin(2x)}$
2. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(\cos(x))}{e^{\sin(x)}}$

Thanks

Comment: The both ones do not exist.

Comment: For the second, examine the function value when (i) $x=2n\pi$, where $n$ is large and (ii) when $x=(2n+1)\pi$, where $n$ is large. The first yields to a similar idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a general result:

> If $f$ is a non constant periodic function then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)$ doesn't exist.

**Sketch of the proof:** Assume that $f$ has the period $T>0$ and the limit $\ell$ and since $f$ isn't constant then there's $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$ and let 
$$\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$$

Can you find $A$ such that $|f(x)-\ell|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>A$?

Comment: I'm baaaack! ;-)

Comment: Apparently, some of my editing and tag-additions were seen as "self-serving"??